# Количество заходов на страницу из поисковиков из Google Analitics API или API Яндекс Метрики

Tags: google-analytics

Как с помощью Google Analitics API или API Яндекс Метрики получить отчет со списком страниц  сайта и количеством заходов на эти страницы из поисковиков за период времени?

Answer (score 2):

Для яндекс метрики - если есть список страниц, просто вешаем на каждую по цели, содержащей url (можно использовать регулярки) и потом получаем  [целевой отчет](https://tech.yandex.ru/metrika/doc/ref/reference/get-counter-goal-docpage/), где будет количество визитов и хитов. Для получения данных по всему сайту подойдет [отчет по посещаемости](https://tech.yandex.ru/metrika/doc/ref/stat/traffic-summary-docpage/)

Так же возможно [новое API метрики](https://tech.yandex.ru/metrika/doc/beta/api_v1/attributes/hitspageview_/url-docpage/) позволит получить информацию не используя цели, но этот способ не пробовал

Answer (score 1):

Для Google Analytics:

- [Visualizing Google Analytics Data with Google Chart Tools](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gdataAnalyticsCharts)
- [Core Reporting API - Common Queries](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gdataCommonQueries)

Comment: насколько я понял там только для одной страницы за запрос можно вытащить данные?